# Catching the right bus

Tags: probability

If buses go every $1$ minute, every $2$ minutes, every $5$ minutes and every $15$ minutes and you turn up at the bus stop at a random point, what is the probability that the next bus to arrive is one of the every $15$ minutes ones?

We can assume that the timetable is set to make this as unlikely as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

0% probability.

Assuming the timetable is set to make this as unlikely as possible consider having the 1 min bus arrive every minute on the minute, ie 12:00, 12:01, etc.  Then make the 15 minute bus arrive at 12:00 + epsilon, 12:15 + epsilon, etc.

Comment: A very good point. I should have said that bus timetables are rounded to the nearest minute. So two buses can be scheduled to arrive at the same time and if one those is the "every 15 minutes bus" and they are due to come next then it counts as the next bus.

Comment: Even if this was the schedule, we have a $\varepsilon/15\rm{\,min}$ chance of the next bus being a 15-minute bus, haven't we?

Answer (score 1):

The hour has $60$ minutes, the 'good' busses run at minutes $0$, $15$, $30$, $45$. If you pick a random minute, the probably for it to be $14$, $29$, $44$ or $59$ is $\frac 4{60} = \frac 1{15}$. For any other minute, there will be a $1$-minute bus next, with no $15$-minute bus scheduled at the same time.